# Ajax No Refresh when Deleting Data in a Table - Laravel

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel, eloquent

My problem is I can click the button but it is needed to refresh to delete it . it there something that is making my ajax code a problem why it is refreshing? I want a button when click delete it will automatically delete without refreshing.

my **Button**

```
<button type="button" data-client_id="{{ $client->id }}" class="btn-archive btn btn-info">Active</button>

<button type="button" data-client_id="{{ $client->id }}" class="btn-delete fa fa-trash btn btn-danger"></button>
```

my **AJAX**

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('click','.btn-archive',function(){
   var clientID=$(this).attr('data-client_id');
   var url='/admin/clients/archTrash/'+clientID;
   callAjax(url);
});

$(document).on('click','.btn-delete',function(){
   var clientID=$(this).attr('data-client_id');
   var url='/admin/clients/archTrashPermanent/'+clientID;
   callAjax(url);
});

function callAjax(url){
   $.ajax({
       url:url,
       dataType:'json',
       type:'GET',
       success:function(response){
          console.log(response);
       },
       error:function(err){
         console.log(err);
       }
   });
}
</script>
```

Table Structure

`
 class Client extends Model
{
     use SoftDeletes;

```
 protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
 // Table Name
 protected $table = 'clients';
 // Primary Key
 public $primaryKey = 'id';
 // Timestamps
 public $timestamps = true;`
```

Comment: Are you deleting a row or just data? It is not very clear in your question.

Comment: @Daniel hi sir, i am deleting each rows is what I what sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: can you help me sir? im stuck here :( @Daniel

Comment: Provide your table structure.

Comment: Ive added my model pls see

Comment: You can try to index your table row and remove it. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_deleterow.asp ..So you have options.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I am doing:

When creating the table, I attach a unique id (user-id in this case) to every row that can be deleted. This is how I do it in blade:

```
@foreach ($visitors as $visitor)
    <tr class="data-user-id-{{$visitor->id}}">
        <td class="text-left">
            {{$visitor->name}}
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" data-original-value="11">
            {{$visitor->email}}
        </td>
        <td class="text-left">
            <a href="#" data-user-id="{{$visitor->id}}" class="btn btn-small btn-info btn-visitor-enable-disable">
                Enable
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left">
           <a href="#" data-user-id="{{$visitor->id}}" class="btn btn-small btn-danger btn-visitor-delete">
              X
           </a>
         </td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

Then, in the success method of my .ajax call, I just select that row using the unique id of the row that was deleted and remove the row. This is how I do it.

```
$(".btn-visitor-delete").on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const userId = $(this).attr('data-user-id');
    var confirmation = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?");
    if (confirmation) {
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'/dashboard/allwhitelistedusers/delete/' + userId,
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            // data:{user_id: userId},
            success:function(data){
                //Refresh the grid
                $(".data-user-id-"+userId).remove();
                alert(data.success);
            },
            error: function(e){
                alert(e.error);
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        //alert ('no');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if u want to delete a record in larval without refreshing the page using ajax so use the below code. I am using this code and its working fine

1. sending id to ajax in this button class which u can relate to yours id `<button class="deleteRecord btn btn-danger" data-id="{{ $party->id }}" >Delete Record</button>`
2. ajax code`is like this with sweet alert`

$(".deleteRecord").click(function(){

```
var id = $(this).data("id");
var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
var parent = $(this).parent();

  swal({
                  title: "Wait..!",
                  text: "Are You sure, You want to delete Party?",
                  icon: "warning",
                  buttons: true,
                  dangerMode: true,
                }).then((willDelete) => {

                    if (willDelete) {
$.ajax({
    url: "delete_party/"+id,
    type: 'DELETE',
    data: {
        "id": id,
        "_token": token,
    },
    success: function (){

           parent.slideUp(300, function () {
                parent.closest("tr").remove();
            });


    },
    error: function() {

        alert('error');
    },
});
  

   } else {

         swal("Your Party is safe");
   }
```

});

});

``

Answer (score 0):

You are only doing half the work: Data is sent to the server and it seems everything is working as expected on that site. But then you want to "delete a client" (I assume you expect a table row to disappear) without reloading the page. You need to code this inside the success handler:

```
success: function(response) {
    $('#client-data').remove();
    console.log(response);
}
```

Note this example code will always remove the same element with the ID `client-data`. You'll probably need to use something like `$(this).parent().remove();` as there seem to be multiple delete buttons on your page.

Comment: do i need to provide u the table structure?

Comment: You are correct @Pida , do you think that is the missing code on my code? Why? What is the logic behind your code?

Comment: Lastly where should I put that code on my ajax code? Sorry im not that well familiar in ajax. Also, the 'client-data" where did you get the name? Can u pls explain it more explictly? Thank you

Comment: The idea simply is to update the page. Let's say you have 10 clients. At the moment, you're just instructing the server to delete one of them from the database. But your page will still display 10 rows until you reload it or remove one row with JavaScript. Yes, please show us your table structure. `client-data` is just a placeholder.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh right yeah correct! But the `client-data` im confused. I dont have a client-data name on my input forms. Where should I put client data? Or i shouldnt worry about it?

Comment: Ive added the model is that what you need sir?

Comment: No, please post HTML for your table.

Comment: Idk how to do that sorry im also new in coding sir, but are y confident that your code is the missing code on my ajax code?

Comment: I'll show you a simpler solution: Insert `location.reload();` directly after `console.log(response);`. This will make your page reload automatically. It seems you are learning Laravel. Have a look at the [free intro on the Laracasts website](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018)

Comment: Okay sir ill try that later but for now u earn a marked answer thank you for elaborating me things idk bout ajax in laravel thnk u